# JSON encoding wrongly escaped (Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, encoding

In my controller, the following works (prints "oké")

```
puts obj.inspect
```

But this doesn't (renders "ok\u00e9")

```
render :json => obj
```

Apparently the `to_json` method escapes unicode characters. Is there an option to prevent this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you dig through the source you'll eventually come to [`ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/3.0.1/ActiveSupport/JSON/Encoding) and the [`escape`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/3.0.1/ActiveSupport/JSON/Encoding.escape) method:

```
def escape(string)
  if string.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
    string = string.encode(::Encoding::UTF_8, :undef => :replace).force_encoding(::Encoding::BINARY)
  end
  json = string.
    gsub(escape_regex) { |s| ESCAPED_CHARS[s] }.
    gsub(/([\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|
           [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|
           [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3})+/nx) { |s|
    s.unpack("U*").pack("n*").unpack("H*")[0].gsub(/.{4}/n, '\\\\u\&')
  }
  json = %("#{json}")
  json.force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8) if json.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
  json
end
```

The various `gsub` calls are forcing non-ASCII UTF-8 to the `\uXXXX` notation that you're seeing. Hex encoded UTF-8 should be acceptable to anything that processes JSON but you could always post-process the JSON (or monkey patch in a modified JSON escaper) to convert the `\uXXXX` notation to raw UTF-8 if necessary.

I'd agree that forcing JSON to be 7bit-clean is a bit bogus but there you go.

Short answer: no.

Answer (score 34):

To set the \uXXXX codes back to utf-8:

```
json_string.gsub!(/\\u([0-9a-z]{4})/) {|s| [$1.to_i(16)].pack("U")}
```

Answer (score 21):

You can prevent it by monkey patching the method mentioned by muu is too short. Put the following into config/initializers/patches.rb (or similar file used for patching stuff) and restart your rails process for the change to take affect.

```
module ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding
  class << self
    def escape(string)
      if string.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
        string = string.encode(::Encoding::UTF_8, :undef => :replace).force_encoding(::Encoding::BINARY)
      end
      json = string.gsub(escape_regex) { |s| ESCAPED_CHARS[s] }
      json = %("#{json}")
      json.force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8) if json.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
      json
    end
  end
end
```

Be adviced that there's no guarantee that the patch will work with future versions of ActiveSupport. The version used when writing this post is 3.1.3.

Comment: As much as I hate doing this, it totally solved my Emoji in JSON issues. Thanks!

Comment: Still a problem in Rails 3.1.6, and this patch still fixes it. The Rails team really need to fix this issue in their JSON encoding; emoji is not something that is going away, especially now that it is part of the Unicode standard.

Comment: see this for a less scary solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683989/how-do-you-deal-with-the-conflict-between-activesupportjson-and-the-json-gem/3285570#3285570

Answer (score 13):

Characters were not escaped to unicode with the other methods in `Rails2.3.11/Ruby1.8` so I used the following:

```
render :json => JSON::dump(obj)
```

Comment: This still works for me in Rails 4.2.5 / Ruby 2.2.3

Comment: Worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

That is the correct encoding.  JSON doesn't *requre* Unicode characters to be escaped, but it is common for JSON libraries to produce output which contains only 7-bit ASCII characters, to avoid any potential encoding problems in transit.

Any JSON interpreter will be able to consume that string and reproduce the original.  To see this in action, just type `javascript:alert("ok\u00e9")` into your browser's location bar.

Answer (score 4):

render :json will call .to_json on the object if it's not a string.  You can avoid this problem by doing:

```
render :json => JSON.generate(obj)
```

This will by pass a string directly and therefore avoid the call to  ActiveSupport's to_json.

Another approach would be to override to_json on the object you are serializing, so in that case, you could do something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_json(options = {})
    JSON.generate(as_json)
  end
end
```

And if you use ActiveModelSerializers, you can solve this problem by overriding to_json in your serializer:

```
# controller
respond_with foo, :serializer => MySerializer

# serializer
attributes :bar, :baz

def to_json(options = {})
  JSON.generate(serializable_hash)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a very tricky way to solve this problem. Well, if `to_json` did not allow you to have the correct code, then you could directly try to write :

```
render text: tags
```

`render json: tags` or `render json: tags.to_json` will always auto transfer the encoding style, but if you use `render text:tags`, then the string will stay as it is. And I think jQuery could still recognize the data.