# toJSON and UTF8 string encoding error in Ruby on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, utf-8

I've got problem with UTF8 string exported using to_json.

The problem is that when I do this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > "anche il più remoto".encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > {:text => "anche il più remoto"}.to_json
 => "{\"text\":\"anche il pi\\u00f9 remoto\"}" 
{:text => "anche il più remoto"}.to_json.encoding
 => #<Encoding:US-ASCII> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 >
```

How can i skip changing the encoding? I want to return UTF8 string to the clients so they don't have decode it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON encoding wrongly escaped (Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123993/json-encoding-wrongly-escaped-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using json or ruby-json gem? From [here](https://github.com/mockko/livereload/pull/90), it's looking like ruby-json is having problems.

Try

```
s.add_dependency('json', '>= 1.5.3')  # this
s.add_dependency('ruby-json', '>= 1.1.2')   # not this

# and

require 'json' #this
require 'json/objects' # not this
```