# Sending emoji from iPhone to android

Tags: android, iphone, emoji

I am developing an android and iPhone apps that has a chat feature in them.

I have implemented emoji support for both.
Android keboards are using SoftBank emoji coding which iPhone understands, but I have a problem with iPhone -> Android messaging with emoji.
For example when choosing the "Pile of Poo" (SoftBank coding 0xe05a) in iPhone 2 chars are sent:
0xD83D 0xDCA9

How can I convert these chars back to SoftBank coding?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat duplicated [how to convert the old emoji encoding to the latest encoding in iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856775/how-to-convert-the-old-emoji-encoding-to-the-latest-encoding-in-ios5)

Please also aware of the affected iOS version.

The table map can be found [here](http://punchdrunker.github.com/iOSEmoji/table_html/) . It seems that the code 0xD83D 0xDCA9 is correct UTF16 encoding.

Comment: the chars sent from iPhone for this emoji symbol are not the unified code point (1F4A9)... maybe a UTF8/unicode issue?

Comment: @Guy see edited answer. You can check the table map and see where your conversion goes wrong. To map back and from SB code, you would need lookup table.

Comment: That helped, thanks! but I ran the string containing the emoji and got that as UTF-8 in my device (Samsung, Galaxy s2)