# Converting emoji to unicode

Tags: objective-c, emoji

I'm trying to convert emoji to unicode characters. I tried using the second option suggested in this solution: [iOS 5: How to convert an Emoji to a unicode character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635393/ios-5-how-to-convert-an-emoji-to-a-unicode-character)
but my output in my tableviewcell label just looks like this:
\ud83d\ude0b
Here's the code from saving the comment:

```
NSData *dataString = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"body" : goodValue };
//and so forth it is saved to the cloud
```

And here's the conversion back to emoji:

```
NSData *data = [self.comment.body dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.bodyLabel.text = goodValue;
```

Comment: Is `NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"body" :body };` and `self.bodyLabel.text = self.comment.body;` doesn't work?

Comment: No they work they just output the \sdfsdlfjsdf stuff

Comment: In the first bit of code, what is `body` and where did it come from?

Comment: If it output `\sdfsdlfjsdf` then in body you have `\sdfsdlfjsdf` instead emojis.

Comment: body is self.commentTextView.textView.text

Comment: Then what's the point of the conversion? You have a string from the text view already. If you want a string for the label, why go through the seemingly pointless conversion to/from data?

Comment: Because in my label i want to see the emoji, so I'm attempting to convert it back, but it isnt working

Comment: Don't convert back and forward. Just assign.

Comment: Why don't you simply do `someLabel.text = someTextView.text;`? There is no reason (that you have explained anyway) why you need some strange conversion.

Comment: Add the unicode character you want by copy/past like:  because \ud83d\ude0b is invalid.

Comment: ^^the server can't handle it