# Bug in ruby JSON lib when handling 4-byte Unicode emoji?

Tags: ruby, json, unicode, emoji

"\360\237\230\204" is a standard emoji icon (U+1f604)

When I try to send this character down in a server endpoint that speaks JSON, the response is mangled. Here is why:

```
>> JSON({:a => "\360\237\230\204"}.to_json)
=> {"a"=>"\357\230\204"}
```

As you can see, the first part of the string has been modified by the JSON library.

Is this a known bug, and is there a workaround? Or is this by design somehow, since the value returned in hex is f604 instead of 1f604?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the same behaviour in 1.9.2.  It shows `\u1F604`.

Comment: @d11wtq: I see the reported behavior using 1.9.2 and a Rails 3.1 console.

Comment: @muistooshort, yeah, I just tried it in IRB. Looks like the issue was solved anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a conflict between ActiveRecord and the standard JSON to_json method. The ActiveRecord to_json implementation had a bug. I solved it using the initializer specified in this thread:

[How do you deal with the conflict between ActiveSupport::JSON and the JSON gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683989/how-do-you-deal-with-the-conflict-between-activesupportjson-and-the-json-gem/3285570#3285570)

Answer (score 0):

try to use Oj:

```
Oj.dump(data, mode: :compat)
```

You will have to add `oj` it to your gem list