# rails: how to not encode on attribute of model when calling render :json => model

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, json, unicode

I've got a column called message in one of my model (UserMessage) in rails.  Now message can contain emoticon value which I passed in from an iphone app.

For example, the smiley icon has the unicode value of U+1F604 and since it's passed in with json format, it's serialize to "\u{1F604}" in my database (postgres).

Now all is fine until I call `render :json => @user_message` in my controller.  Rails take the serialized message "\u{1F604}" and call ActiveSupport::JSON.encode on it and therefore encode it again.  I've try to override to_json in the UserMessage class to no avail.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: How is it getting to be `"\u{1F604}"`? That is not a JSON string literal format, which would be `"\uD83D\uDE04"`.

Comment: @bobince This is the result of the JSONKit library in iOS.  Even if I have "\uD83D\uDE04" in the database, calling to_json on it still won't be right.

Comment: Indeed, if you are receiving JSON data you should be JSON-decoding any strings you have before you put them in the database. Are you sure you should be sending it JSON-encoded data? It would be normal to just use form-encoded data surely?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683989/how-do-you-deal-with-the-conflict-between-activesupportjson-and-the-json-gem/3285570#3285570