# Upgrade to Rails 4 got IOError (not opened for reading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I try to upgrade an app from 3.2 to rails 4. i think all the gems conflicts have been solved at the moment though later i know it might happen again.

While i try to "bundle exec rails s" and open the app in browser go the app home index, it gives me this error:

**IOError (not opened for reading)**

Could anyone help with this? Thank you so much.

here is the gem list i used:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
# add these gems to help with the transition:
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem "activerecord-session_store"
```

And here is the log message for console:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-06 20:16:27 +1100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  PCategory Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "p_categories".* FROM "p_categories"
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

IOError (not opened for reading):
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:256:in `each'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:256:in `to_a'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:256:in `as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:58:in `block in as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:81:in 'check_for_circular_references'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:57:in `as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `block in as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `each'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `map'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:58:in `block in as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:81:in g`check_for_circular_references'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:57:in `as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `block in as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `each'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `map'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `as_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:50:in `block in encode'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:81:in `check_for_circular_references'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:49:in `encode'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:306:in `block in encode_json'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:306:in `each'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:306:in `map'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you deal with the conflict between ActiveSupport::JSON and the JSON gem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683989/how-do-you-deal-with-the-conflict-between-activesupportjson-and-the-json-gem)

Answer (score 4):

Turns out a GEM conflict was the culprit of a similar issue that I had. I fixed the problem with the code from an indirectly related question that used Rails instead. Please see below, I hope this helps you.

```
#fix for JSON gem/activesupport bug. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683989/how-do-you-deal-with-the-conflict-between-activesupportjson-and-the-json-gem
if defined?(ActiveSupport::JSON)
  [Object, Array, FalseClass, Float, Hash, Integer, NilClass, String, TrueClass].each do |klass|
    klass.class_eval do
      def to_json(*args)
        super(args)
      end
      def as_json(*args)
        super(args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Which gem was the problem?

Comment: This was a long time ago I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue recently myself. After a few days of trial and error, I eventually commented out a set of development group gems (lucky guess), then re-enabled each gem one by one, rebuilding my gem set with each newly enabled gem. The culprit turned out to be the [MetaRequest](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel/tree/master/meta_request) gem and its dependency, [rack-contrib](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib) (which does some JSONP work).

So here's what I suggest:

> 1. Empty your gem set (`rvm gemset empty` if you're using rvm)
> 2. Rename your Gemfile.lock file to Gemfile.lock.OLD (this may not be necessary, but listed just in case)
> 3. In your Gemfile, comment out any gems that you suspect handle requests or do any JSON work
> 4. Run `bundle install` to rebuild your gem set without the commented-out gems
> 5. Restart your server. If you still receive the IOError, repeat steps 1-5. Otherwise, proceed to step 6.
> 6. Un-comment one of the gems you commented out
> 7. Run `bundle install` to install the gem and its dependencies
> 8. Restart your server. If you don't encounter the IOError, repeat steps 6-8. Otherwise, the gem you re-enabled last is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this with ActiveModel Serializers gem. I upgraded ActiveModel Serializers from 0.8.1 to 0.9 and it worked fine after that.