# Ruby IO Error, not opened for reading

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra

Using OmniAuth for Facebook with Sinatra and Ruby 1.9.3. Getting the IO not opened for reading error during the latter stage of the auth process. Haven't seen much else about this online. If you require any more info please let me know.

Failing on the MultiJson line:

```
get '/auth/failure' do
content_type 'application/json'
MultiJson.encode(request.env)
end
```

Error:

IOError at /auth/facebook/callback
not opened for reading
file: encoding.rb location: each line: 256

Detailed error log:

```
== Sinatra/1.4.4 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:86:in `new'.

127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2013 18:34:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0025
I, [2013-12-08T18:34:03.828713 #927]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2013 18:34:03] "GET /auth/facebook HTTP/1.1" 302 203 0.0049
I, [2013-12-08T18:34:04.278981 #927]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
IOError - not opened for reading:
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:256:in `each'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:256:in `to_a'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:256:in `as_json'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:58:in `block in as_json'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:81:in `check_for_circular_references'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:57:in `as_json'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `block in as_json'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `each'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `map'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:296:in `as_json'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:50:in `block in encode'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:81:in `check_for_circular_references'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:49:in `encode'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:34:in `encode'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:16:in `to_json'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/multi_json-1.8.2/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:21:in `dump'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/multi_json-1.8.2/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:24:in `dump'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/multi_json-1.8.2/lib/multi_json.rb:137:in `dump'
    app.rb:87:in `block in <main>'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1593:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1593:in `block in compile!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:957:in `[]'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:957:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:976:in `route_eval'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:957:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:997:in `block in process_route'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:995:in `catch'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:995:in `process_route'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:955:in `block in route!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:954:in `each'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:954:in `route!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in dispatch!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1049:in `block in invoke'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1049:in `catch'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1049:in `invoke'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1064:in `dispatch!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:889:in `block in call!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1049:in `block in invoke'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1049:in `catch'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1049:in `invoke'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:889:in `call!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:877:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:401:in `call_app!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:363:in `callback_phase'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/omniauth-oauth2-1.0.3/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:65:in `callback_phase'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `callback_call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:182:in `call!'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-protection-1.5.1/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-protection-1.5.1/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-protection-1.5.1/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-protection-1.5.1/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:50:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-protection-1.5.1/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:50:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:217:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:210:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:180:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2004:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1469:in `block in call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1778:in `synchronize'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1469:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:1037:in `call'
    /Users/philhudson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:1037:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a GEM conflict was the issue. I fixed the problem with the code from [an indirectly related question that used Rails instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683989/how-do-you-deal-with-the-conflict-between-activesupportjson-and-the-json-gem). Please see below:

```
#fix for JSON gem/activesupport bug. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683989/how-do-you-deal-with-the-conflict-between-activesupportjson-and-the-json-gem
if defined?(ActiveSupport::JSON)
  [Object, Array, FalseClass, Float, Hash, Integer, NilClass, String, TrueClass].each do |klass|
    klass.class_eval do
      def to_json(*args)
        super(args)
      end
      def as_json(*args)
        super(args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```